# C++ is it possible to create an array of strings of different sizes or functionally similar?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, dynamic

I'm writing a program that needs a feature where it writes strings to a file. It's a logging system of sorts that pushes a string to a new line in the text file then retrieves them later.

The issue is I only need to retrieve the last few, but how many I need to retrieve and the size of each string is dynamic. So the program increments an int every time a line is added to file to know how many lines there are, which will end up being hundreds maybe thousands.

It then can retrieve a line based on that int so it knows what the last line is:

```
//Super simplified
int count = 0;

void write_line_to_file(std::string _line)
{
   file.add(_line);
   count++;
}

std::string read_line_from_file(_line_num)
{
   file.getline(_line_num);
}
```

What I don't know how to do is make a variable data structure that can resize based on how many lines ill need to retrieve for a given moment. There's a variable screen size that determines how big the logging area is. It could be 3 lines tall, could be 50. So I need a function that uses the `read_line_from_file` function to place only the last X amount of entries.

The function of this system is supposed to be to read the logging area as new entries are added but there's so many its unrealistic to load the whole file into memory. I'm also going to add a function that lets you scroll up and replaces the oldest line with the line that's 1 older and shifts everything.

My current "solution" is:

```
std::string log_line1;
std::string log_line2;
std::string log_line3;
std::string log_line4;

void update_log_area()
{
   log_line1 = read_line_from_file(count);
   log_line2 = read_line_from_file(count-1);
   log_line3 = read_line_from_file(count-2);
   log_line4 = read_line_from_file(count-3);
   ...
   // all the way to log_line10
}
```

It's not variable so when its increased to say 50 lines, only 10 will be visible, leaving 40 blank. But when it's down to a single line visible at a time. It's performing 9 extra reads, and reassigning 9 extra variables. I thought about doing an array but each line varies from 1 character to a string of hundreds.

So if I were to prepare for worst case scenario and choose the biggest possible size string a string could be and make the array for the most lines possibly visible at a given time, it would be an array of thousands of bytes large:

```
// terrible performant, only current idea to make it modular

int max_string_len = 500;
int count = 0;
const int max_log_lines = 65;
std::string log_line[max_log_lines];
int cur_shown_lines = 1;

void write_line_to_file(std::string _line)
{
   std::string new_line;

   int string_len = sizeof(_line) //not actual code, just imagine one that returns # of chars in string
   if (string_len < max_string_len)
   {
      new_line = _line;
      int diff_in_len = max_string_len - string_len;
      for (int i = 0; i < diff_in_len - 1; i++)
      {new_line += " ";} // not actually how the overload works but it would functionally just add blank spaces until the string length equals the max_string_len
   }
   else
   {new_line = _line;}

   file.add(new_line);
   count++;
}

std::string read_line_from_file(_line_num)
{
   file.getline(_line_num);
}

void update_log_area()
{   
   for (int i = 0; i < max_log_lines-1; i++)
   {
      log_line[i] = read_line_from_file(count-i);
   }
}

void change_lines_shown(cur_shown_lines)
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= cur_shown_lines-1; i++)
  {
    move_cursor(i); //writes a string to a line. 0 being bottom/most new and every number up is one older
    cout << log_line[i];
  }
}
```

Just to potentially display a single character on a single line at a time because it's possible the last entry is a single digit number and the log area is only 1 line. I intend to scale this up as well so these performance issues would compound.

If anyone knows a better way please let me know. I know this is long so thank you in advance.

Edit: I'm still learning C++ and hadn't looked into std::vector. As a few people commented, it is exactly what I needed. For some reason I assumed std::vector was a mathematical vector

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: I can only guess that you haven't studied `std::vector` yet, which is odd because you clearly know `std::string`. Anyway it's perfect for your needs.

Comment: BTW the correct code for returning the number of chars in a string is `_line.size()`. Again I find it slightly odd that you know `sizeof` is not correct but apparantly don't know about `.size()`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you need/want a fixed size: `std::array<std::string, FixedSize>` – note that the `std::string` objects themselves do dynamic allocation (apart from potential short string optimisation), so you don't run into arrays of arrays of fixed size as in `char strArray[FixedSize][MaxLength]`.

Comment: For `std::string` I personally would rather prefer `length()` over `size()`, but that's not the matter, they both do the same...

Comment: About the terrible performance you complain about: You already created a *copy* of the input parameter (`_line`) – so modify that one instead of creating yet another one (`new_line`); you can simply do by `if(line.length() < minimum) { line.resize(minimum, ' '); }` which avoids your potentially inefficient (multiple re-allocations) loop as well. If you have a 'maximum' then you might want to truncate too long strings as well – then all that remains is `{ line.resize(ExactLength, ' '); file.add(line); ++count; }` where `resize` truncates or fills up spaces, if need be either of.

Comment: And you can avoid a copy entirely if the string matches your requirements already if you accept by `const` reference: `void write(std::string const& line) { if(line.length() == ExactLength /* >= MinimumLength */) { file.add(line) } else { std::string tmp(line); tmp.resize(MinimumLength, ' '); file.add(tmp); } ++count; } }

Comment: Possible XY-problem: Regarding your setting, a thousand lines is *nothing* unless each line is itself a million characters, but that is usually no longer treated as a line-oriented file. So it unclear why you are repeatedly reading/writing to the file. Is it used as some sort I/O where the user can edit a line? Otherwise just read the entire thing in one go or mmap it.